# How do I transfer money from a bank account to a bitcoin address

Tags: bitcoin-cash, payment, money-transfer

I need to pay money into a bitcoin wallet address from a South African bank account, please assist

Comment: I know that you say you need to buy bitcoin but, you have tagged bitcoin-cash which is different (unless you meant it to say 'pay cash for bitcoin'?). I hope you know the difference before you make an order.

Answer (score 2):

Banks hold and transfer fiat currency.  The Bitcoin network holds and transfers a token called Bitcoin.  What you are looking for is someone who is willing to sell you Bitcoin in exchange for some of the fiat currency in your bank account.  This is fundamentally different than transferring money from a bank account to a bitcoin address.

What you need is an exchange.  There are several to choose from, but you will need to find one that accepts payments from a South African bank.  Product and service reviews are considered off topic on this site, so you may want to look elsewhere to find an exchange that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://coinbase.com to help you convert it (note: ONLY 18+ can use it).

Answer (score 0):

A quick internet search gives me this result:

Buy Bitcoin in South Africa
https://www.buybitcoinworldwide.com/south-africa/

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, this Bitcoin wallet works in all countries, including with African countries https://polehin.com. Although, perhaps there are better analogues. I would generally make some sort of comparison list